# python tk loading buttons from a list of buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a set of dictionaries that link to other dictionaries as shown:

```
Mods = {"links_too":["module_1","module_2","module_3","module_5","module_6"],"Buttons":[],"previous":Mods}
module_1 = {"links_too":[],"Buttons":[],"previous":Mods}
module_2 = {"links_too":["chap1","chap2"],"Buttons":[],"previous":Mods}
all_dics = (Mods,module_1,module_2)
```

I use this list to create a button for each linked dictionary in a for loop:

```
def create_menu_buttons():
    #for every dictionary in the list
    for y in all_dics:

        #for every dictionary in the links too create a button for that dictionary 
        for x in y["links_too"]:
            z = [x + "_button"]
            z = ttk.Button(window,text=x)
            z.config(command=lambda x=x:nav_load_screen(x))
            y["Buttons"].append(z)
```

i want to load them into my window with a function:

```
def nav_load_screen(dic):
    clear_window() #clears the window
    axis_x = 0
    axis_y = 1
    for but in dic["Buttons"]:
        but.grid(column=axis_x,row=axis_y)
        if axis_x == 9:
            axis_x = 0
            axis_y = axis_y + 1
        else:
            axis_x = axis_x + 1
```

When this is ran the code doesnt recognize dic as a list i think this may be because it is being passed in as a string? if anyone cknows what is going on that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have variables (with those names) that *are* `tk.Button` or `ttk.Button` objects, you can just put those variable names into a list and then iterate over them. Basically, you just need to remove the quotes so the list items aren't interpreted as `str`ings.

```
# These buttons already exist, like you said...this is just an example :)
module_1_button = tk.Button(...)
module_2_button = tk.Button(...)
module_3_button = tk.Button(...)

# put your buttons in a list more or less like before
buttons = [module_1_button, module_2_button, module_3_button]  # note the lack of quotes!


# iterate over the buttons and pack() them as you like
def nav_load_screen():  # no need to pass the list in since it's global
    clear_window() #clears the window
    axis_x = 0
    axis_y = 1
    for but in buttons:
        but.grid(column=axis_x, row=axis_y)
        if axis_x == 9:
            axis_x = 0
            axis_y = axis_y + 1
        else:
            axis_x = axis_x + 1


nav_load_screen()  # call the function
```

Comment: line 4, in <module>
    buttons = [module_1_button, module_2_button, module_3_button]
NameError: name 'module_1_button' is not defined

Comment: @toyotaSupra I’m not getting this error, but this code won’t run as-is…some assumptions are made regarding OP’s code which isn’t shown

Comment: i understand that this works but again i cannot change how my buttons are stored so this would not work. i am creating the button in a for loop so unless there is a way to create and store the buttons as themselves and not strings this will not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that shows how the buttons are created and I'll see what I can come up with :)

Comment: apologies i restructured the question to take on your advice of changing how the buttons are stored but i got similar issues. i also included more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are iterating over the `button` list and the `but` in the for loop is variable which will print the `module_1_button, module_2_button, module_3_button`  after each iteration...

To have the button names according to the list you have to specify the main window where you want you buttons:

It will be like this:

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry('500x200')
buttons = ['module_1_button', 'module_2_button', 'module_3_button']

def nav_load_screen():
    clear_window() #clears the window
    axis_x = 0
    axis_y = 1
    for but in buttons:
        B = tkinter.Button(top, text = but)
        B.grid(column=axis_x,row=axis_y)
        if axis_x == 9:
            axis_x = 0
            axis_y = axis_y + 1
        else:
            axis_x = axis_x + 1
nav_load_screen()
top.mainloop()
```

You does not need to provide an argument to the  `nav_load_screen` function as you already declared list of the button..

Hope it will helpful to you

Comment: The buttons exist already with there own attributes. i simply need to be able to call and place them in the window. this just creates new buttons and over writes the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

After some messing about i changed 2 thing that made it work:

1)
in the `nav_load_screen` function i changed the for loop too look for the dictionary in `globals()`:

```
def nav_load_screen(dic):
    clear_window() #clears window of widgets
    axis_x = 0
    axis_y = 1
    for but in globals()[dic]["Buttons"]:
        but.grid(column=axis_x,row=axis_y)
        if axis_x == 9:
            axis_x = 0
            axis_y = axis_y + 1
        else:
            axis_x = axis_x + 1
```

My understanding of `globals()` is that it is a list of sorts containing all variables, lists, dictionaries, etc... and that the program can find the dictionary in there.

after this i got the error: `str has no atribute "buttons"`

2.
I then tweaked the `create_menu_buttons` function to change the varables as shown:

```
def create_menu_buttons():
    #for every dictionary in the list
    for y in all_dics:

        #for every dictionary in the links too create a button for that 
        for x in y["links_too"]:
            z = x
            x = [x + "_button"]
            x = ttk.Button(window,text=z)
            x.config(command=lambda z=z:nav_load_screen(z))
            y["Buttons"].append(x)
```

I have absolutely 0 clue why this worked. i think it could be because a variable is used instead of the variable in the for loop. if anyone knows why the second part works that would be great.